# Extending the admin import form for django import_export

Tags: django-admin, django-import-export

I'm using [Django import_export](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export) to implement CSV upload in my admin pages. Now I have one model, that contains a foreign key column, but the foreign key column will have only one value for each import. Therefore I would like to allow the user to choose the related model instance from a drop-down instead of forcing the user to append the columns themselves. In order to do this I need to customize the import form, which requires overriding the default methods `import_action` and `process_import`, but my efforts so far have shown no effect. Here is what I have so far:

```
from django import forms
from import_export.forms import ImportForm  
from .models import MyModel, RelatedModel

class CustomImportForm(ImportForm):
    """Add a model choice field for a given model to the standard form."""
    appended_instance = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)

    def __init__(self, choice_model, import_formats, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomImportForm, self).__init__(import_formats, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['appended_instance'].queryset = choice_model.objects.all()

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = SomeResource


    def import_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().import_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        form = CustomImportForm(RelatedModel, 
                                import_formats,
                                request.POST or None,
                                request.FILES or None)
```

Now when I go the import page I get the `AttributeError MyModelAdmin has no attribute 'POST'` and in the local vars I can see that the `request object` is actually the `MyModelAdmin` class, which is I believe is not what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, this is an old post, but I ran into this, when looking on how to override the import_action.
Your error is here:
`super().import_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`

You should call it without the self:

`super().import_action(request, *args, **kwargs)`

or for older python:

`super(MyModelAdmin, self).import_action(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 2):

Avoid reimplementing either `import_action()` or `process_import()`; partially because they're fairly complex and fragile methods, but more importantly because there are neater ways of doing this using the existing hooks in the Import/Export API. [See this answer for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335510/extend-django-import-exports-import-form-to-specify-fixed-value-for-each-import/53607729#53607729)

Answer (score 0):

```
    def import_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       response = super(MyModelAdmin, self).import_action(request, *args, **kwargs)
       context = response.context_data
       import_formats = self.get_import_formats()
       context['form'] = CustomImportForm(RelatedModel, import_formats, request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
       return TemplateResponse(request, [self.import_template_name], context)
```