# Extend django-import-export's import form to specify fixed value for each imported row

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-import-export

I am using django-import-export 1.0.1 with admin integration in Django 2.1.1. I have two models

```
from django.db import models

class Sector(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)

class Location(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    sector = ForeignKey(Sector, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='locations')
```

and they can be imported/exported just fine using model resources

```
from import_export import resources
from import_export.fields import Field
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget

class SectorResource(resources.ModelResource):
    code = Field(attribute='code', column_name='Sector')
    class Meta:
        model = Sector
        import_id_fields = ('code',)

class LocationResource(resources.ModelResource):
    code = Field(attribute='code', column_name='Location')
    sector = Field(attribute='sector', column_name='Sector',
                   widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Sector, 'code'))
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        import_id_fields = ('code',)
```

and import/export actions can be integrated into the admin by

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class SectorAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = SectorResource

class LocationAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = LocationResource

admin.site.register(Sector, SectorAdmin)
admin.site.register(Location, LocationAdmin)
```

For *Reasons™*, I would like to change this set-up so that a spreadsheet of `Locations` which does *not* contain a Sector column can be imported; the value of `sector` (for each imported row) should be taken from an extra field on the `ImportForm` in the admin.

Such a field can indeed be added by overriding `import_action` on the `ModelAdmin` as described in [Extending the admin import form for django import_export](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48949993/268113). The next step, to use this value for all imported rows, is missing there, and I have not been able to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT(2):** Solved through the use of sessions. Having a `get_confirm_import_form` hook would *still* really help here, but even better would be having the existing `ConfirmImportForm` carry across all the submitted fields & values from the initial import form.

**EDIT:** I'm sorry, I thought I had this nailed, but my own code wasn't working as well as I thought it was. This *doesn't* solve the problem of passing along the `sector` form field in the `ConfirmImportForm`, which is necessary for the import to complete. Currently looking for a solution which doesn't involve pasting the whole of `import_action()` into an `ImportMixin` subclass. Having a `get_confirm_import_form()` hook would help a lot here.

Still working on a solution for myself, and when I have one I'll update this too.

---

Don't override `import_action`. It's a big complicated method that you don't want to replicate. More importantly, as I discovered today: there are easier ways of doing this.

First (as you mentioned), make a custom import form for `Location` that allows the user to choose a `Sector`:

```
class LocationImportForm(ImportForm):
    sector = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, queryset=Sector.objects.all())
```

In the Resource API, there's a `before_import_row()` hook that is called once per row. So, implement that in your `LocationResource` class, and use it to add the `Sector` column:

```
def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
    sector = self.request.POST.get('sector', None)
    if contract:
        self.request.session['import_context_sector'] = sector
    else:
        # if this raises a KeyError, we want to know about it.
        # It means that we got to a point of importing data without
        # contract context, and we don't want to continue.
        try:
            sector = self.request.session['import_context_sector']
        except KeyError as e:
            raise Exception("Sector context failure on row import, " +
                                 f"check resources.py for more info: {e}")
    row['sector'] = sector
```

(**Note:** This code uses Django sessions to carry the `sector` value from the import form to the import confirmation screen. If you're not using sessions, you'll need to find another way to do it.)

This is all you need to get the extra data in, and it works for both the dry-run preview and the actual import.

Note that `self.request` doesn't exist in the default `ModelResource` - we have to install it by giving `LocationResource` a custom constructor:

```
def __init__(self, request=None):
    super()
    self.request = request
```

(Don't worry about `self.request` sticking around. Each `LocationResource` instance doesn't persist beyond a single request.)

The `request` isn't usually passed to the `ModelResource` constructor, so we need to add it to the kwargs dict for that call. Fortunately, Django Import/Export has a dedicated hook for that. Override `ImportExportModelAdmin`'s `get_resource_kwargs` method in `LocationAdmin`:

```
def get_resource_kwargs(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    rk = super().get_resource_kwargs(request, *args, **kwargs)
    rk['request'] = request
    return rk
```

And that's all you need.

Comment: I tried your answer but unfortunately, the class **resources.ModelResource** does not have an attribute *request*. Where did you get the session from?

Comment: See the section 2/3 of the way down the answer - line starts with "Note that `self.request` doesn't exist..."